# Запуск bash скрипта из Asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, bash

Подскажите есть ли идеи как можно запустить bash скрипт из Asp.net ? скорее всего через контролер web api. Сами скрипты будут находится в той же директории что и dll. Или просто как можно линукс команды запустить

Comment: Ну минимум поставить последний `.net` на линукс и посмотреть где взорвётся.

Comment: cмешной ты, в чем проблема поставить  .net на линукс ? ) .net core с 2016 года есть

Comment: Ну раз ты в курсе, что он есть с 2016-го года - почему до сих пор не поставил и не посмотрел что отвалилось? Или ты не знаешь синтаксис запуска внешних комманд из asp?

Comment: ставил и нормально все работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого класс Process. Подробное описание и примеры работы с классом:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process

По сути вам надо в качестве параметров указывать те же значения, которые вы бы указывали для запуска скрипта из консоли/терминала.

Comment: спасибо! забыл совсем про process, конкретно по bash нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987600/how-to-run-bash-cmd-in-dot-net-core